# windows 7 64bit rc with SSD saving problem

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ssd

I have this problem where, in any application, 95% of the time when i try to save it pops up with a "Save As" dialogue. And if i try to select the original file i get an error popup "The operation could not be completed".

I have Windows 7 RC 64bit with a X-25M SSD. I have upgraded the firmware for the SSD just in case and still the problem persists.

Has anyone come across this before or know the problem?

Or is there some indication i should be looking for in the event logs?

Thanks

Comment: ive also asked here http://serverfault.com/questions/93984/windows-7-64bit-rc-with-ssd-saving-problem but it was suggested that i post here

Comment: Check your event logs for any disk failure in the system / application log.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, you may not be able to save to certain directories (such as C:\Windows, C:\Program Files, etc.) unless the application is run as an administrator.

Comment: its saving to a folder under c: that i have created. It would reject me all the time and not most times if that were the case.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you are trying to save to a folder that you have created.

- But under which circumstances did you
  create this folder?
- As an administrator?
- With which user account are you
  running the applications?
- Have you tried to run the application as an
  administrator?
  If so, what is the result?
- Has somebody else saved the current
  file with other permissions than your
  current account?

My guess is that it is a permissions issue. When the Save As dialog pops up instead of saving the file, most certainly the current file can't be opened/saved. Probably because of permissions and/or the file is read only or locked.
Download and run SysInterals procmon, filter on your file name, and watch what the result is when saving the file.